# Need to click a link on body load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a domain www.example.com . I have created a subdirectory discount and it has a index.php file. What I want is that when a user mouses over www.example.com, along with the website this discount page also open up in lightbox. I know how to do this via prettyphoto(Lighbox open up when you click on discount link), but the problem is how to trigger this action on page load.

Comment: Hi Guys,Thanks for your help. i am a beginner in javascript, so have not been able to quite pick up your comments. I am giving my codes below. I don't know why click event is not firing up. Can you please help "<body onload="document.getElementById('link').click();">
 
 <a id="link" href="discount/discount.php ?iframe=true&amp;width=802&amp;height=510" rel="prettyPhoto[iframe]"> Test </a>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PrettyPhoto gives us the `.open` call, wich I believe can be used to directly open a modal box, with no need to click, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $.prettyPhoto.open('images/image.jpg','Title','Description');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this triggers on document ready

```
$(document).ready(function()
                       {
                           //todo
                       });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just trigger the `click` event in the `ready` handler. I've assumed the `id` of your link is `#link`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#link').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onload` event of the window object:

```
window.onload = function()
{
  // Show your lightbox!
}
```

You are already using jQuery, so you could write this, too:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  // Show your lightbox!
});
```